# Custom actions to filter junk mail arriving in Junk mailbox aren't executed

Tags: mail.app, ventura, mail-rules

I receive a lot of junk mail that is sent to hms92@mac.com. I’ve found that I can set up a rule based on the Original-Recipient header that matches with “rfc822:hms92@mac.com” to delete most of these emails. This rule works perfectly when invoked manually.

What I would like to do is have these emails sent to the trash *before* they arrive in my Junk folder. This should be possible, because according to Mail > Settings > Junk Mail, if I set up a custom action with this rule (and with the setting checked “Filter junk mail before applying my rules”), I would expect the very same rule configured as a custom action to do this.

However, it doesn’t work. The spam with this Original-Recipient header “rfc822:hms92@mac.com” arrives normally in my Junk folder without being sent to the Trash or deleted.

Do custom actions work for anyone? I've filed FB12213605 with Apple.

Comment: Wouldn't it need 'filter junk mail…' to be *off* to hit your rule first?

Comment: Rules are only applied to the Inbox

Comment: @mmmmmm - do you have citation for that? It's not that I don't believe you, it's that I'm sure sometime in the past I've built a bad rule & accepted the 'do it now' button as you leave the zone & then regretted what happened. As it's something I will never do again, my recall is somewhat hazy on what *actually* happened.